# How to flatten two columns in sql table?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table which includes two columns with arrays one representing the currency (['EUR', 'GBP', ...]) and the other the rates for the currency to USD (['1.10', '1.23', ...]). Every new update is a new row with timestamp and transaction hash (it is from ethereum network).

In order to use them more easily, I would like to flatten the table so every rate, currency, timestamp and transaction hash would be in its own row.

This is my attempt:

```
SELECT * FROM `main_table`
CROSS JOIN (
UNNEST(tickers) AS ticker 
INNER JOIN UNNEST(rates) AS rate)
```

*I am using BigQuery*

Comment: Can you please include some sample data -- what you currently have and what you would like to see as a result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is to use offsets:

```
SELECT *
FROM `main_table` t CROSS JOIN
     UNNEST(t.tickers) WITH OFFSET tn LEFT JOIN
     UNNEST(t.rates) WITH OFFSET rn
     ON tn = rn
```